# Scripting through SMO

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, smo

Is it possible to run a script using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo?

I am able to generate script using the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter class. I would like to edit it and run it to create copy of database objects.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.  The other option is to use the SQLCommand object.

```
string script = "create procedure b as select getdate()";
Database db = new Database(new Server("ServerName"), "DBName");
db.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
```